# Sketch: As a symbol, adding text will resize the text block height

Tags: text, sketch-app, resize, symbols

I have an article block as a symbol in sketch. It contains an image, headline and paragraph. When using the symbol in my canvas, I'd like to change the title, but once it drops to two lines, it will cover the paragraph. Is there any way to prevent this from happening? I tried using the resize tool, but I might be doing it wrong.

Comment: Hey, if you either share how the design looks or a sketch file with it, we'll find you a solution.

Answer (score 5):

I'm desperately looking for an overall solution for this as well. The little workaround I've found until now, is a solution where you at least can compensate the look for one text object dropping to 2 lines.

1. I set the text field i want to allow growing to multiple lines in the resizing setting to pin to the top
2. I set the rest of the objects following this text field underneath to pin to the bottom
3. I put in my overwrites and as soon as the text drops to 2 lines I adjust the height of that symbol and make it current height+[lineheight of the textfield]

[image: resizing symbols that have overwrites that cause 1 textline to drop to 2 lines and more]